# From where Sheshnaag came?

Tags: vishnu, adisesha

I have read many scriptures but not sure about how sheshnaag became a bed for God Vishnu. Prabhu sheshnaag is son of kadru and he was granted a responsibility by Brahma to hold earth on his head. Any other information regarding this is helpful, and please correct me if I am missing anything.